# JS touch events equivalent to mousedown

Tags: javascript, html

time trying increase a number by one when clicked/touched and by many when held. This is working with a mouse (seems a bit buggy). but how can I get it to work with a touch device using the "touch" event?

I would like to do it like below because I have many buttons that do the same job. also in pure JS please.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var count = 0;
  var iv = null;

  ["btn-1", "btn-2"].forEach(function(object) {
    ["click", "mousedown", "mouseup", "mouseleave", "touchstart"].forEach(function(event) {
      document.getElementById(object).addEventListener(event, function() {
        if (event == "mousedown" | "click" | "touchstart") {
          iv = setInterval(function() {
            if (object == "btn-1") {
              count++;
            } else {
              count--;
            }
            document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
          }, 100);

        } else {
          clearInterval(iv);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#btn-1 {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}

#btn-2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.6em;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}

#count {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4em;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn-1">button up</button>
  <button id="btn-2">button down</button>
  <label id=count>0</label>
</body>
```

Comment: "click" and "mousedown" are triggered in the same time.

Comment: cool so i only need to use one. cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you change your condition to `if (event == "mousedown" || event == "click" || event == "touchstart")` it will work. At least, it works for me. `|` is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and when used like you used it, everything comes to a undefined behaviour.

Edit: I think the `mousedown` event works because first the condition `event == "mousedown"` is evaluated, which results into true. In the end, we have, `true | "click" | "touchstart"` which returns also true.

However, for click and touchstart, the first comparation returns false, and `false | "click" | "touchstart"` return false, so the condition will never execute.

Hope this helped you.
Cheers!

```js
console.log("mousedown" | "click" | "touchstart")

event = "mousedown";
console.log(event == "mousedown" | "click" | "touchstart")
console.log(true | "click" | "touchstart")

event = "click";
console.log(event == "mousedown" | "click" | "touchstart")

event = "touchstart";
console.log(event == "mousedown" | "click" | "touchstart")
```

Comment: really good answer thank you! Il try it in the morning to see if it help. it makes a lot of sense 